# Why does this retain previously clicked ids after on('click') on a list-group-item?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have the following part of my chatroom code:

**HTML**

```
<div class="list-group">
  <a class="list-group-item" id="1" href="#">Group A</a>
  <a class="list-group-item" id="2" href="#">Group B</a>
  <a class="list-group-item" id="3" href="#">Group C</a>
  <a class="list-group-item" id="4" href="#">Group D</a>
</div>

<div class="message_box">
  <form action="#" class="form">
    <div class="form-group"></div>
    <div class="input-group">
      <textarea class="form-control message_text emojiable-message"
                name="message_text" id="message_text" rows="3"></textarea>
      <span class="input-group-addon btn btn-primary send_message_btn" name="send_message_btn"
            >
        Send
      </span>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

**jQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#groups a.list-group-item').on('click', function () {
    $(this).toggleClass("active");
        $(this).siblings().removeClass("active");

        //chage the textarea and btn id to single user.
        $('.send_message_btn').removeAttr('id');
        $('.send_message_btn').attr('id', 'send_to_topic');

        var selected_group_id = this.id;

        //Handle enter key press and mouse click (group)
        $('#send_to_topic').click(function(e) {

            alert(selected_group_id);

            //sendChatMessage(selected_group_id);
            return false;
        });

        $('#message_text').keydown(function(e) {
            if (e.keyCode == 13) {

                alert(selected_group_id);

                //sendChatMessage(selected_group_id);
                return false;
            }
        });

        $(this).removeClass('active');
        $(this).removeAttr('id');
  });
});
```

The problem is when I select several list-group-item and then hit send button, the `alert(selected_group_id);` prints the ids of all the items I had selected. I just want to pick the last selected item to use in `sendChatMessage(selected_group_id);` . If someone could point out where am going wrong that would be great. Thanks.

> Edit.
>   The main problem is when I hit send the message gets delivered in duplicates (number of all list-group-item ids I had selected before sending). If I just select one group and send the message does not duplicate (which is okay.).

Comment: you are attaching `$('#send_to_topic').click(` and `$('#message_text').keydown` event handler multiple times as and when somebody clicks on `$('#groups a.list-group-item')`. Please move those outside of upper `click` handler.

Comment: @vijayP thanks for the reply. It makes no difference even when I move the textarea keydown and button click handler outside of  `$('#groups a.list-group-item').on('click', function () { `

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modified your HTML and JS code a bit and its working here. Please have a look at it.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('a.list-group-item').on('click', function() {
    $(this).toggleClass("active");
    $(this).siblings().removeClass("active");
  });

  //Handle enter key press and mouse click (group)
  $('#send_to_topic').click(function(e) {

    var selected_group_id = $(".list-group .active").attr("id");
    alert(selected_group_id);

    return false;
  });

  $('#message_text').keydown(function(e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 13) {
      var selected_group_id = $(".list-group .active").attr("id");
      alert(selected_group_id);

      //sendChatMessage(selected_group_id);
      return false;
    }
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="list-group">
  <a class="list-group-item" id="1" href="#">Group A</a>
  <a class="list-group-item" id="2" href="#">Group B</a>
  <a class="list-group-item" id="3" href="#">Group C</a>
  <a class="list-group-item" id="4" href="#">Group D</a>
</div>

<div class="message_box">
  <form action="#" class="form">
    <div class="form-group"></div>
    <div class="input-group">
      <textarea class="form-control message_text emojiable-message" name="message_text" id="message_text" rows="3"></textarea>
      <span class="input-group-addon btn btn-primary send_message_btn" name="send_message_btn" id="send_to_topic">
        Send
      </span>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

As vijayP suggested, your `$('#send_to_topic').click()` and `$('#message_text').keydown()` should live outside of the `$('#groups a.list-group-item').click()` event.

Next, since your `selected_group_id` variable is declared with the var keyword, it is not accessible by functions outside of the `$('#groups a.list-group-item').click()`'s scope.
So you should declare this variable outside all these events like so :

**jQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    // Declare the selected_group_id outside of the events so they can access to it
    var selected_group_id;

    $('#groups a.list-group-item').on('click', function () {
        $(this).toggleClass("active");
        $(this).siblings().removeClass("active");

        //chage the textarea and btn id to single user.
        $('.send_message_btn').removeAttr('id');
        $('.send_message_btn').attr('id', 'send_to_topic');

        selected_group_id = this.id;

        $(this).removeClass('active');
        $(this).removeAttr('id');
    });

    //Handle enter key press and mouse click (group)
    $('#send_to_topic').click(function(e) {

        alert(selected_group_id);

        //sendChatMessage(selected_group_id);
        return false;
    });

    $('#message_text').keydown(function(e) {
        if (e.keyCode == 13) {

            alert(selected_group_id);

            //sendChatMessage(selected_group_id);
            return false;
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: The same problem is still there. If I click on several `list-group-item`s before hitting send on one of them, `alert(selected_group_id);` prints the id of the current selected item followed by the previously selected item id's. If I uncomment `sendChatMessage(selected_group_id);` multiple counts of the same message is sent.